# Add or Remove a Mark on Image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image

I've a html DIV as follows

```
<div id="mapimage" style="background-image: url('images/physical-map.jpg'); width: 500; height: 548; background-repeat: no-repeat"></div>
```

To add a mark on this DIV background image, I'm doing as following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#mapimage').mousedown(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
                var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                var img = $('<img>');
                img.css('top', y);
                img.css('left', x);
                img.attr('src', 'images/red-dot.png');
                img.appendTo('#mapimage');
    });
```

This is working fine, What I need is -
First time, I'll add a mark at position (10,122) on a DIV. And If I click on same position on Second time, The added mark should be removed from there. How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a mark?  Are you trying to add and remove a watermark on an image?  If so, you can do this by either a. creating two images and swapping between them, or b. create your main image and then have a transparent watermark image placed over it.  Am I missing the point?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the `img` and remove that class everytime your map image is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#mapimage').mousedown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // remove all images
        $('.remove-me').remove();

        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.attr('src', 'images/red-dot.png');

        // add a class to the image
        img.addClass('remove-me');

        img.appendTo('#mapimage');
    });
});
```

**Or**

Instead of removing all images everytime the map is clicked, simply remove the image that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // remove images that are clicked
    $('.remove-me').on('click', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $('div#mapimage').mousedown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.css('top', y);
        img.css('left', x);
        img.attr('src', 'images/red-dot.png');

        // add a class to the image
        img.addClass('remove-me');

        img.appendTo('#mapimage');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Buddy, I updated the Jquery, now the **.on()** is working, But my purpose is not satisfied... :(